# How to debug fsockopen?

Tags: php, fsockopen

How can I understand the error when trying to open a socket?
I get error 0, however all SSL certificate works fine.

```
$fp = fsockopen("ssl://cloud-messaging.bitrix24.com", 443, $errno, $errstr);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "ERROR: $errno - $errstr<br />\n: " . $errno;
    print_r($errstr);
} else {
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Result:

ERROR: 0 - 
: 0

But it works when I try to open the socket with myself.

Maybe there is some script that will allow you to get at least some error?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Does [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075434/fsockopen-returning-server-error0) answer your question in any way?

Comment: `ssl://` is not a protocol. Use  `$fp = fsockopen("cloud-messaging.bitrix24.com", 443, $errno, $errstr);`

Comment: @Jamie_D hostname
If OpenSSL support is installed, you may prefix the hostname with either ssl:// or tls:// to use an SSL or TLS client connection over TCP/IP to connect to the remote host.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

Comment: Good catch! However, if [cloud-messaging.bitrix24.com](https://cloud-messaging.bitrix24.com) is indeed the URL you are using, you will get an error since `fsocketopen`  doesn't do redirects. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23504713/get-final-url-from-fsockopen)

Comment: @Jamie_D The problem is that this code is used by the system to test the health of sockets

Comment: If that's the case than all you may need is [socket_get_status](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-get-status.php) which is an alias of [stream_get_meta_data](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-meta-data.php)

Comment: I added a Gist for you here using the URL:

https://gist.github.com/Fliktrax/f111b10e8019da98a89cd5cd25943af7

Comment: @Jamie_D Result = null.

I think the problem is that my server supports TLS1.0 and TLS1.1
https://i.imgur.com/L2jr3gB.png

Comment: You can remove that with just `SSLProtocol TLSv1.2` in your virtual host/SSL setup